# What do you call these long spoons?

Tags: utensils

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Jtt2-8wv1w) the cook uses a really nifty long spoon.

[image]

What would you call such a thing and where would be the best bet to purchase one? I'm pretty certain the spoon is long because you cannot get too close to the industrial burners used in that restaurant, but that is a nice piece of kit for the home cook as well.

Comment: We shouldn't have to watch up to 18 minutes of external resource just to spot what you mean. Upload a still.

Comment: Not quite that long or large of a bowl, but there are also ‘ice tea spoons’

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Long handle spoons." ...just search [the webstaurant store](https://www.webstaurantstore.com/) and you will find plenty.